# User-ID view not populating even though I am following all the right steps

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Folks, 
I have looked high and low but seem to be totally stymied now. To capture login-ID as userID in Google Analytics, we have done the following
1. Create a userID view in GA(Google Analytics) 
2. Create a custom dimension in GA
3. Add a Data layer variable in Google Tag Manager(GTM)called userID
4. Add the variable as fields to be set within the "fields to Set". Also added the custom dimension as a field to be set.

When I publish the tag, the User-ID view stays stubbornly unpopulated. I have tested and the dataLayer variable is showing up fine in the preview mode.

I have defined userID be uniform throughout with the same upper and lower case spelling. However, in other instructions on how to do this https://www.clickinsight.ca/about/blog/implement-user-id-tracking
they have changed the case of the variable. Does the variable name need to be a particular way for Google Analytics to capture the data?

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom dimension is not actually necessary. Google Analytics does not expose the userId via the interface, so you may add a custom dimension if you want to use it in the reports, but the userId view works without it.

The tutorial you linked is a bit confusing since they use a different case for the GTM variable (userID) and the GA field (userId). While this is technically correct it would probably be easier if they used a unified spelling (casing ?).

The field name for the field that needs to be set in Google Analytics is userId (capital "i", small "d") per the [analytics.js field reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#userId) (the tutorial has it correctly in its screen shots, but again you might have gotten confused by the different spellings in the text).